# What is the clean way to store information get from web service in angularJS?

Tags: web-services, angularjs

I've got a front-end Angular App which get information from server side on a REST API.
When I make requests, I'd like to do it only once and so, keep the data in the front app.

I found several examples but either:

- the logic is in controller -> not a good practice
- variables are stored in the root scope -> not a good practice in general

I was told to use services to do this.
For example, from what I understood, I should have a service which GET user profile, and another one which keep these information (a "profile" service) once the GET request has been made.

Could someone show me how to do this if my service to call GET request is something like this:

```
.factory('userPromise', ['$http', '$q', 'baseUrl',
                          function ($http, $q, baseUrl) {
    return {
        getUser: function(usn, uid, key) {
            return $http.get(baseUrl + 'business_infos/' + parseInt(uid) + '/'
                             + '?format=json&username=' + usn + '&api_key=' + key).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Note that I don't want to just cache information. I want to create a user profile from what I get that can contain other information.

it would be something like:

```
{
    profile:  {
        firstname: "Thierry",
        lastname: "Chatel"
    },
    hasRole: function (role) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service has a config which says to `cache` the response or not. If set to `true` a framework level cache will be available. If you want you can specify a [`$cacheFactory`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) in the config. Same is applicable for `$resource` service.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to just cache information. I want to create a userprofile from what I get that can contain other information. I updated my question to be more specific. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for cacheFactory, you can cahce data and get it.
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough in my question. I updated it, thank you.